# Which competing technologies are similar to Ethereum?

Tags: altcoin

Ethereum is widely known for its smart contract system, but which other competing technologies are also out there that does something similar. Just like in the early days of Bitcoin, many clone coins followed after. Which ones have come before or after Ethereum?

Answer (score 4):

- [Rootstock](http://www.rootstock.io/)
- [Eris](https://erisindustries.com/)
- Various ethereum forks,

  - There are a few in the [altcoin](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=67.0) section of bitcointalk
- Various applications that claim some scripting ability (though many do not)

  - [crypti](https://crypti.me/)
  - [nxt](http://nxt.org/)
  - qora
  - [burst](http://burstcoin.info/)

Answer (score 3):

Major ones that pre-date Ethereum:

- BitShares
- OMNI (formerly known as Mastercoin)
- NXT
- Counterparty (uses the Bitcoin blockchain)

An upcoming one I'm aware of: [Rootstock](http://www.rootstock.io/)

Comment: what are the differences and why are they competing. what do they have in common? please try to add some details to your answer.

Comment: @acros: OP specifically asked about smart contracts, hence the "programmable" blockchain. Can you, as a dev, write smart contracts in Bitshares and OMNI/MasterCoin?  Seen that Rootstock.io is basically a port of Ethereum to Bitcoin, I agree with Rootstock.  But I'm really not sure BTS and OMNI/MasterCoin qualify as "programmable blockchains" / smart contracts / whatever you want to call that.